# I get different results using between condition with dates including milliseconds precision in MariaDB

Tags: sql, datetime, count, mariadb, where-clause

I got the following `Sales` table with columns `productName Varchar(50)` and `saleDate bigint(20)`.

Let's suppose it stores 100 records.

Examples:

```
productName saleDate
----------- ------------
TV          1601555334694
Radio       1603585354888
...
```

The `saleDate` column stores in timestamp number with date with milliseconds precision. Then I run the following queries to get the number of sales in October 2020:

```
-- This returns a result of 70
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT productName, 
  DATE_FORMAT(SUBSTRING(DATE_ADD((FROM_UNIXTIME(SUBSTRING(saleDate, 1, 10)) -
  INTERVAL (10+5*60) MINUTE), INTERVAL SUBSTRING(saleDate, 11, 13) SECOND_MICROSECOND),1,23), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS saleDate
  FROM Sales
) s
WHERE s.saleDate between '2020-10-01 00:00:00' and '2020-10-31 23:59:59.999'

-- This returns a result of 20
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT productName, 
  DATE_FORMAT(SUBSTRING(DATE_ADD((FROM_UNIXTIME(SUBSTRING(saleDate, 1, 10)) -
  INTERVAL (10+5*60) MINUTE), INTERVAL SUBSTRING(saleDate, 11, 13) SECOND_MICROSECOND),1,23), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS saleDate
  FROM Sales
) s
WHERE s.saleDate between '2020-10-01 00:00:00.000' and '2020-10-31 23:59:59.999'
```

I'm subtracting the date 5 hours with 10 minutes less in both queries. It's system requirement.

So When I filter the begin date with .000 the result changes. Shouldn't be the same result of 70?

I'm using Mariadb 10.2.13

Comment: Why not use a DATE type column to hold your date, or a TimeStamp type

Comment: Well that's according to the defined db model. I can't change it.

Comment: `s.saleDate` is a string, not a timestamp, and it doesn't have milliseconds in it.

Comment: Yes. It's working as a string. I tried to remove "DATE_FORMAT(SUBSTRING(", not DATE_ADD but I get other result of quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend translating the interval bounds to unix timestamps instead of proceeding the other way around. This is simpler, and much more efficient: the `where` predicate is SARGable (meaning that it may take advantage of an index on `saledate`), while, in your original query, the entire column needs to be converted before it can be filtered.

Also, using half-open intervals saves your from handling the trailing milliseconds.

So:

```
select count(*)
from sales
where saledate >= unix_timestamp('2020-10-01') * 1000
  and saledate <  unix_timestamp('2020-11-01') * 1000
```

If you want to offset by 5 hours and 10 minutes, then that's simple artithmetics:

```
select count(*)
from sales
where saledate >= (unix_timestamp('2020-10-01') + 5 * 60 * 60 + 10 * 60) * 1000
  and saledate <  (unix_timestamp('2020-11-01') + 5 * 60 * 60 + 10 * 60) * 1000
```

Comment: I tested the last query with ofsset. According to the example, it gives 70 which is good because it tells me that the first query I've shown returns the same result even it's not efficient. I recognize your query is efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `DATE_FORMAT()` format string doesn't include the milliseconds. So if the value of `saleDate` is exactly `2020-10-01 00:00:00`, it won't satisfy the `BETWEEN` condition, since `2020-10-01 00:00:00` is not lexicographically higher than `2020-10-01 00:00:00.000`.

Either add the milliseconds to the format string `'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000'`
or remove the milliseconds from the times you use in `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Good point. I tested and it returns 70. I got question. How does the comparison of the Between condition work internally? Maybe the begin and end date is converted into timestamp or bits sequence and then starts the comparison.

Comment: `x BETWEEN y AND z` is just a shortcut for `x >= y AND x <= z`. Nothing is converted to timestamps. `DATE_FORMAT()` returns a string, and `'2020-10-01 00:00:00'` is a string, so it just does string comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Just something to think about...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT 99-i j FROM ints ORDER BY i;
+----+
| j  |
+----+
| 99 |
| 98 |
| 97 |
| 96 |
| 95 |
| 94 |
| 93 |
| 92 |
| 91 |
| 90 |
+----+

SELECT 99-i i FROM ints ORDER BY i;
+----+
| i  |
+----+
| 90 |
| 91 |
| 92 |
| 93 |
| 94 |
| 95 |
| 96 |
| 97 |
| 98 |
| 99 |
+----+
```